# Equivalent of healthcheck test in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: bash, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have this `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.11.2
    environment: 
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=sns,sqs
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - bash
        - -c
        - awslocal sns list-topics
          && awslocal sqs list-queues
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

with that, it checks the healtheck taking advantage that the container has `awslocal` command available.

What would be the equivalent for GitLab assuming I need to run some tests against localstack and I want to wait for localstack service to be up and running before?

Something like this:

```
tests:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack:0.11.2
      alias: localstack
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
    EDGE_PORT: "4566"
    SERVICES: "sns,sqs"
  before_script:
    # should I use before_script? is there a better way? What's the linux command to test the same and wait?
  script: dotnet test --blame --configuration Release
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/**/*Tests.csproj
```

---

UPDATE 1:
One possible trick is using the `before_script`, but happy to hear about better built-in solutions. Also this does not work as

```
/bin/bash: line 125: awslocal: command not found
Failed rounds=9
```

but here's my attempt

```
tests:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack:0.11.2
      alias: localstack
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
    EDGE_PORT: "4566"
    SERVICES: "sns,sqs"
  before_script:
    - rounds=10;
      while [ $rounds -gt 0 ]; do
        awslocal sns list-topics && awslocal sqs list-queues && echo OK && break || echo Failed
        rounds=$(($rounds - 1));
        sleep 5;
      done;
  script: dotnet test --blame --configuration Release
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/**/*Tests.csproj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible working solution. Notice that I cannot use awslocal within the service despite of having awslocal available inside the localstack container (maybe something needs to be mounted).

In any case I solved it with a simple curl.

```
tests:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: localstack/localstack:0.11.2
      alias: localstack
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
    EDGE_PORT: "4566"
    SERVICES: "sns,sqs"
  before_script:
    - rounds=10;
      while [ $rounds -gt 0 ]; do
        curl http://localstack:4566 && echo OK && break || echo FAIL
        rounds=$rounds - 1;
        sleep 5;
      done;
  script: dotnet test --blame --configuration Release
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/**/*Tests.csproj
```